# How to make test suite spanning multiple files and run from command line?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I need to make a test suite incorporating slow tests from several different files, and run from command line. I am testing one file at a time, and don't want to move these slow tests, the most logical way to organize is to test them next to their neighboring functions.

I can't even find how to run test suites from command line, without which they seem to have no purpose. I'd like to run all tests in this suite, something like `python -m unittest slow`, and only run the tests that aren't in the slow suite when I run regular, `python -m unittest`.